# I need to make the text in carousel to be responsive

Tags: html, css

I have used bootstrap 4 classes and media queries but the text disappears when I look up the site on phone.`   
    
        
        
        
        
    
    
        
            
            
                -----any text ------- 
                -----any text -------
                ---any text---

```
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src=" img2.png" alt="Second slide" style="height: auto">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block n28">
            <h1 class="n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h1>
            <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img3.png" alt="Third slide" style="height: auto">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block n28">
            <h1 class="n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h1>
            <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

```
  .carousel-caption{
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
transform: translateY(-50);}
 .carousel-caption h1{
font-size: 500%;}
 .carousel-caption h3{
font-size: 110%;
font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check CSS in Media script for classes of your text, might be display property set to none. either these classes "n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" or these "animated bounceInLeft".

Comment: it doesnt showing the text even if i remove the class and display property also isnt set to none

Comment: then check javaScript might be there is some other classes called by jQuery for particular screen size.  run your website in firefox developer edition with responsive design mode(ctrl+shift+m) and move screen size and check for which screen size text is disappear. find out the class and css and screen size as well, add your css for the same screen size to display text.

Answer (score 0):

i made this and responsive. please check it. Thanks

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.carousel-caption { display:none;}

}
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cruxnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Natural-cemetery-Natuurbegraafplaats-Koningsakker-1024x576.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block n28">
            <h1 class="n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h1>
            <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cruxnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Natural-cemetery-Natuurbegraafplaats-Koningsakker-1024x576.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block n28">
            <h1 class="n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h1>
            <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cruxnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Natural-cemetery-Natuurbegraafplaats-Koningsakker-1024x576.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block n28">
            <h1 class="n26 animated bounceInRight display-2" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h1>
            <h3 class="animated bounceInLeft" style="animation-delay: 0.5s">-----any text -------</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it not working still it disappears